# is it possible to make object just transparent without reflection reflation

Tags: transparency, glass

as you can see when it reflects it looks so weird, is it possible to make these glasses just transparent without so much reflection.

[image]

Comment: you can mix your Principled BSDF with a Transprent node?

Comment: Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1):

Create a *Shader > Mix Shader* and mix your current node with a *Transparent* node, play with the *Mix Shader* factor to give your material more or less transparency.

That said I'm not sure about your *Principled BSDF* settings, you need to put the *Transmission* at 1 if you want a glass effect, and also don't forget to choose *Blend Mode > Alpha Blend* in the *Material Settings* if you are in Eevee.